# How to compute a specific value of an amortization schedule in Excel / Libreoffice

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice-calc

I can create loan payoff amortization schedules like in the image included with no problem.

Is it possible to calculate the loan balance in a single cell from the initial conditions of the loan along with what period to calculate it for?

I am trying to build a dashboard showing several loans and I'd like to estimate loan balances relative to TODAY(), so it would have to compute the balance on the spot. I can compute what term of the loan is next up, but is there a way to do the payment loop without actually creating a table?

My other alternatives would be using lookups or VBA but I'd rather not deal with those options if I don't have to. None of the built-in functions seem to do it outright but maybe theres some other way to make it work.

[image: Schedule]

Answer (score 0):

Use the CUMPRINC() formula. This tells you how much principal you paid. Subtract that from the original principal to tell you how much principal you have remaining.

To use TODAY() you'll need the loan start date somewhere in your spreadsheet, and do an INT() on the difference /365 or something like that.

You can test the formula to a couple of your amortization schedule to make sure it's coming up with the same answer